# Is there something like jsfiddle.net for Dart?

Tags: dart, code-snippets

I'd like to be able to try, share and execute online Dart code and I'm looking for something like JsFiddle for Dart. Is there something like this available?

Comment: My bad, I didn't see this similar question :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/). From [What is it? What does it do?](https://github.com/dart-lang/dart-pad#what-is-it-what-does-it-do):

> This project is a web based interactive Dart service. It's meant to be a simple, easy way for users to play with Dart on-line, in a zero-install, zero configuration environment. It'll support an easy snippet sharing service.

At the moment the service is still in beta and has some limitations (eg. you can not use dependencies) but it works really well for simple cases.